# Sorting firebase objects based on long values on android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on an android app that shows times/dates for rides to and from certain locations. I want to sort my firebase objects so that objects are sorted based on date. I tried searching online and playing with the methods `ref.setPriority(...)`, and `ref.orderByChild(...)`, but I cannot find a clear way on doing this.

This is what my database looks like currently

[image: This is what my database looks like currently]

I have the date in a `long` data type, and I want my firebase recycler view to show the rides in ascending order, in terms of how soon the ride is from the current date. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this:

```
Query query = mRideRef.orderByChild("date");
```

And then set a listener to get the values

Comment: awesome, but how can i change the positioning of the firebase recycler items so that they match the order of the query?

Comment: Is there an equalTo with a long value?

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Rosario's answer, I just want to say after creating the query, just inject it into the firebase recycler adapter as the final parameter to get a sorted recycler view. Didn't realize that it had the option but it works perfectly now!